# How can I pick a sibling(?) element using CSS_Selector with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium

ladies and gentlemen.

I am trying to grab the price of an apartment from DOM on this site:
[text](https://www.olx.uz/d/nedvizhimost/kvartiry/arenda-dolgosrochnaya/tashkent/?currency=UZS&search%5Border%5D=created_at%3Adesc&search%5Bfilter_enum_comission%5D%5B0%5D=no&view=list)

The DOM looks like:
[image]

I cannot get the part saying '700 y.e.'

Any ideas how to make way to this element?

I have tried this code. There would be more items with exactly the same structure, so I am trying to use CSS here:

`

```
def get_content(url):
    with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
        driver.get(url)
        grid = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="listing-grid"]')
        cards = [x for x in grid.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-cy="l-card"]') if 'ТОП' not in x.text]
        links = []
        prices = []
        for card in cards:
            url = card.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')
            links.append(url)
            price = card.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p[data-testid="ad-price"]').text
            print(f'the price is {price}')
```

Comment: Could it be Xpath? Or must be CSS 100%?

Comment: What's wrong with this code? It looks OK.

Comment: Do you get any specific error? If not, can you share the result you get compared to the result you want?